# Why do CiviCRM URLs have 'reset=1' in the query string?

Tags: urls

Most CiviCRM URLs have `reset=1` in the query string.

E.g. `http://[yoursite.com]/civicrm?reset=1`

What does this do and does it matter if you don't include it?

I only ask because URLs look nicer without it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`reset=1` clears the current local session variables as well as the smarty cache.

For instance, if you have a form that is getting reused, `reset=1` will clear the form's fields (whereas, without it, the form may contain values carried over from it's prior invocation).

If you don't use it, and it's a public, anonymous facing page, I suspect you may get away with it. Try it and see how it works for you.

If the parameter is necessary, you could add it as a redirect to your installation.  For instance, in your .htaccess file include something like:

`Redirect 301 /contribute https://[yoursite.com]/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=5`

Which would allow `https://[yoursite.com]/contribute` as a valid link to the ultimate contribution page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking of the user facing pages rather than the public pages.  As you say, you can redirect the public facing pages in Drupal using an alias.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to effectively get rid of it on CiviCRM's pages.

You could create some custom pages, a portal in effect, for your users, but that's a lot of work and probably not worth the effort.

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct - the big thing that's not mentioned here is that the smarty cache is cleared with the reset=1. Also, you can't use Drupal path aliases, because Drupal path aliases don't allow query strings. You can setup redirects, which is almost as good.

Comment: Alan is right, Drupal Aliases do not work because of the question mark - when I really need a nice URL I end up putting a redirect in my .htaccess file like so:
`Redirect 301 /contribute https://watershedmg.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=5`